# Удалить массив с повторяющимися значениями

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив с с массивами, в которых лежат данные о пользователях. Пример:

```
subarray = [
 ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Maxim', 'Maximow', 'testmail.com', '03.11.2000', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1997', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Danil', 'Danilov', 'danilov@mail.ru', '02.08.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Vlad', 'Vladov', 'vladov@mail.ru', '08.4.2010', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681']
]
```

Как мне удалить массив, в котором совпадают имя, фамилия и почта? И если год рождения больше, чем 2003 тоже удалять.. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: используй https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Что вы попробовали и что у вас не получилось? Есть масса способов, от базовых алгоритмов до использования специально для этого существующих функций

Comment: @nicael я не могу понять, как мне найти повторяющиеся значения и удалить массив, в котором они повторяются...

Comment: Что такое цикл, вы знаете? Как пройтись по массиву?

Comment: @nicael да, я это делал, я не могу понять саму логику выполнения...

Comment: Как проверить, есть ли в массиве определённый элемент? Какая для этого функция используется?

Comment: @nicael find, includes

Comment: Да самое первое что приходит в голову - это простой, но долгий алгоритм: пройтись циклом в цикле по массиву с двумя указателями и записывать в другой массив все элементы для дальнейшего удаления и потом пройтись по этому массиву и удалять у исходного массива. Т.е. хотелось бы видеть хотябы такие попытки, чтобы потом мы сказали где ошибка и как лучше сделать

Comment: Есть ещё другая, что вернёт индекс. С помощью проверки на то, существует ли текущий элемент на другом индексе, применив фильтрацию, можно очистить массив от дупликатов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для текущей задачи удобно представить данные в структуре с ключом, содержащим определенные поля, и значением описывающим сами данные, т.е. словарь [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Алгоритм:

- Перебираем список списков
- Определяем ключ. Например, для `['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681']` это будет `'Ivan-Ivanov-mail.com'`
- Вытаскиваем год
- Если данных по ключу нет и при этом год рождения подходящий, то добавляем данные
- После перебора в словаре будут только подходящие данные

Пример:

```js
function get_user_key(user) {
    return `${user[0]}-${user[1]}-${user[2]}`;
}

subarray = [
    ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
    ['Maxim', 'Maximow', 'testmail.com', '03.11.2000', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
    ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1997', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
    ['Danil', 'Danilov', 'danilov@mail.ru', '02.08.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
    ['Vlad', 'Vladov', 'vladov@mail.ru', '08.4.2010', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681']
];

key_by_user = new Map();
for (user of subarray) {
    key = get_user_key(user);
    year = parseInt(user[3].split('.')[2]);
    
    if (!key_by_user.has(key) && year <= 2003) {
        key_by_user.set(key, user);
    }
}
// console.log([...key_by_user.entries()]);

for (user of key_by_user.values()) {
    console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: Гении мыслят одинаково :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, ага, спасибо :D

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
const subarray = [
  ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
  ['Maxim', 'Maximow', 'testmail.com', '03.11.2000', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
  ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1997', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
  ['Danil', 'Danilov', 'danilov@mail.ru', '02.08.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
  ['Vlad', 'Vladov', 'vladov@mail.ru', '08.4.2010', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681']
]

const map = new Map();

subarray.forEach(item => {
  const name = item[0];
  const surname = item[1];
  const email = item[2];
  const birthYear = +item[3].split('.')[2];

  const key = `${name}-${surname}-${email}`;

  if (map.has(key) || birthYear > 2003) return;

  map.set(key, item);
});

const filteredSubarray = [...map.values()];

console.log(filteredSubarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько удивлён, почему уже опубликованные алгоритмы такие громоздкие. Я не думаю, что следует выцеплять каждый элемент каждой записи, [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) то на что дан.

<s>Да и к тому же, говорили ведь в комментариях про [фильтрацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))</s> ладно, без неё ещё короче

Моё решение:

- Создать объект. Как мы знаем, у объекта не может быть двух одинаковых ключей, этим мы и воспользуемся.
- Пройтись по массиву и запихнуть в объект каждый элемент массива как значение по ключу, который мы скрафтили из первых трёх значений поля (имя, фамилия и почта) с помощью слайса
- Вывести все значения объекта (на ключи мы забили, они нам были нужны лишь для де-дупликации)

```js
subarray = [
 ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Maxim', 'Maximow', 'testmail.com', '03.11.2000', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Ivan', 'Ivanov', 'mail.com', '03.12.1997', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Danil', 'Danilov', 'danilov@mail.ru', '02.08.1998', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681'],
 ['Vlad', 'Vladov', 'vladov@mail.ru', '08.4.2010', 'Moscow Pushkin street', '54681']
];

obj = {};

subarray.forEach((el) => {
    if(el[3].slice(-4) < 2003)
        obj[el.slice(0,3).join()] = el;
})
   

console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: Если вам непонятна какая-то часть этого немудрого алгоритма, уточните в комментариях, разжую

Comment: то есть алгоритм работает за счет того, что в объекте не может быть одинаковых ключей?

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров да, все верно

Comment: По сути, когда ты по такому же ключу пытаешься записать другое значение, то старое значение просто стирается

Comment: а если бы значения в массиве шли не по порядку, а например Ivan Ivanov 03.10.2000 mail.com.
Как тут добраться до мэйла этим кодом? Подскажи, пожалуйста

Comment: @ДанилСтоляров В данном случае почта есть четвёртый элемент массива, просто выбрать его по индексу [3]. Сам код по фильтрации нужно было бы переписать тоже

Comment: спасибо тебе.. И всем, кто откликнулся. Если тебе не сложно и есть свободное время, можешь пожалуйста объяснить как это делать через filter?

Comment: @nicael Решения которые уже опубликованы  - громоздкие потому что написаны так, чтобы во-первых легче было читать, во-вторых они легко подстраиваемы под какие-то новые условия. `slice` помогает вам только в случае, если вы собираетесь брать непрерывный кусов массива, а может понадобиться 1, 3, 7 элемент, а в-третих каждое ваш вызов `slice` - это лишняя работа с массивом, в то время как можно намного быстрее просто взять нужные элементы.

Comment: @nicael Не воспринимайте моё сообщение очень критично, в вашем алгоритме есть свои плюсы, вы например не проверяете наличие ключа, а просто затираете его, что избавляет от дополнительной проверки, но перед тем как говорить "почему уже опубликованные алгоритмы такие громоздкие" нужно сначала разобраться какие плюсы у этих алгоритмов, потому что опубликованные ответы тоже можно написать в пару строк, но это вредит читабельности кода. Надеюсь на понимание!